# Combining Firebase Authentication with Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an app in Android Studio (Kotlin) that registers users:

[User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpVQT.png)

An email/password user is created (Authentication) along with a corresponding database record (Realtime Database):

[Datbase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Krw.png)

I have the login procedure working and I'm able to display the logged-in user's email address on MainActivity, BUT, I don't know how to display the user's name and favourite colour (from the database).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance for your time.

**RegisterActivity.kt**

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var viewModel: UserViewModel

    public val USER: String = "user"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        register_button.setOnClickListener {

            val email = register_email.text.toString().trim()
            val password = register_password.text.toString().trim()
            val name = register_name.text.toString().trim()
            val colour = register_colour.text.toString().trim()

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

            val user = User()
            user.email = email
            user.name = name
            user.colour = colour

            viewModel.addUser(user)

        }
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        login_button.setOnClickListener {

            val email = login_email.text.toString().trim()
            val password = login_password.text.toString().trim()

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Login Success
                    val intent = Intent (this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                }
            startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    //Login Failure
                    task.exception?.message?.let {
                        toast(it)
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt** (to display User details)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        currentUser?.let { user ->

            main_email.setText(user.email)
            main_name.setText("Don't Know")
            main_colour.setText("Don't Know")
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit 3**

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        login_button.setOnClickListener {

            val email = login_email.text.toString().trim()
            val password = login_password.text.toString().trim()

            loginUser (email, password)

        }
    }

    private fun loginUser(email: String, password: String) {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Login Success
                    val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("username",user.displayName)
                    intent.putExtra("email",user.email)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    //Login Failure
                    task.exception?.message?.let {
                        toast(it)
                    }

                }
            }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        mAuth.currentUser?.let {
            login()
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //I have commented out the line below because it may not be required...
    // private val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //I have commented out the lines below because they may not be required...
        //currentUser?.let { user ->
            //main_email.setText(user.email)
            //main_name.setText("Don't Know")
            //main_colour.setText("Don't Know")
        //}
    }

}
```

ERROR 1 : Overload resolution ambiguity on putExtra
ERROR 2 : Unresolved Reference on user.

[image: Error, full code above ^]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you launch at your login stage

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

It has a callback that will be completed and successful when the user has been logged in, inside that callback, you are already logged in and that user now corresponds to one unique user ID, you can access that user ID by doing

```
val user = FirebaseAuth().getInstance().currentUser.uid
```

Then, here you can fetch that user data and pass it as an extra or bundle to your MainActivity, so the login process will take the time to log the user, fetch its data and send it to the MainActivity, this way you are not delaying any more time the user at your MainActivity

You can see that the user has been created once that successful callback is launch, and then in the Firebase console you can check for that user in the authentication tab

### Edit

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Login Success, here you can get currentUser
                     val user = FirebaseAuth().getInstance().currentUser
                    login(user.displayName,user.email)
                }else{
                    //Login Failure
                    task.exception?.message?.let {
                        toast(it)
                    }

                }
            }
```

Then, just add these two parameters to the login() method and just do a putExtra with those values and send those values as an extra to the main activity, so you are not fetching in your mainactivity and just sending the values from the login

Keep in mind that after `.addonCompleteListener()` the result is your current logged in user, so from here, you can get the currentUser information or the currentUser id

### Edit 2

Inside the onComplete , just pass the data to the MainActivity

```
val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("username",user.displayName)
intent.putExtra("email",user.email)
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in your MainActivity get this extras

```
 val extras = getIntent().extras
        val userName: String?
        val email: String?

        if (extras != null) {
            userName = extras.getString("userame")
            email = extras.getString("email")
        }
```

Then you already have the data from login into your MainActivity

### Edit 3

To change the color, just change it from the MainActivity

```
your_text_view.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.yourColor)
```

Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you Gaston, Can you please check again my LoginActivity code (edited). I have added an OnCompleteListener. Does that look correct? Also, are you sure this will read the database record too?

Comment: Please do not reply yet. I am editing my post again. Thanks

Comment: Ok please check again.

Comment: Thanks, please can you check again my login method, because login() is just the redirect. Instead of using login() I have put my actual code. If you can please modify your sign in method, and also let me know how to display the name and colour on MainActivity (I have included this code also)

Comment: edited now, check it, you should be familiar with bundles and extras to work with data from one activity and another

Comment: Hi Gaston, I'm actually not overly familiar with bundles or extras :(

Comment: I also must mention, I'm just trying to load Favourite Colour as a String. I don't need to change any colours.

Comment: Edited. Under Edit 3 in my post is my latest code. Getting 2 errors and still not sure how to assign those values to my edit text elements. Thanks

Comment: the error is because user does not exists, you did not put     val user = FirebaseAuth().getInstance().currentUser in the competion of the task as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: please, follow this tutorials https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-training/

Comment: This is the codelab you should do to understand what we are doing here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code you wrote was meant as a solution.

Comment: Those tutorials look great. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote is meant as the solution of your question

Comment: I did give you my entire code but you only edited part of it (which gave errors). Clearly I don't understand this as well as I thought, so I better get started on those tutorials. Hopefully then I can find the solution myself. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The thing is that we cant code for you, we find problems on your code and we recommend a better solution, is on you to know how to use the tools that android gives you to work with, using firebase is way harder than passing a bundle, you should check those tutorials

Comment: Yes I understand you cannot code for me. However, sometimes full solutions are provided, and sometimes not. Thanks again for your advice and I'll make a start on those tutorials.